# Does Stackoverflow public dump of data and mirror sites affect its Page Rank?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, data-dump

We started to see SO content duplicated in some sites. Does it affects SO position in Google results?

Comment: I'm unsure about the Page Rank, but the search result order is affected as Jeff posted here http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/01/trouble-in-the-house-of-google.html

Answer (score 4):

StackOverflow content was scraped and used on other sites well before the monthly data dumps started.

Comment: Anyways, does it affect its page rank?

Comment: If anything, it probably raises it because the license for the dump requires attribution.

Comment: As Joel said it should increase page rank since the content sites have links pointing away from their content and towards SO, but SO doesn't point back. If the links aren't `rel="nofollow"` page rank would be near zero. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank#Simplified_algorithm

Answer (score 2):

http://stackmobile.com/ scraped entire network on SO sites and formatted them for mobile browser. Is this OK?

Comment: actually StackMobile uses the StackExchange API.  http://stackapps.com/questions/36/stackmobile-com-view-stackexchange-sites-on-your-smartphone

Comment: OK, cool. So using API is not considered scraping, right?